# Clicking on child DIV inside dropdown

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer

I succeeded already to enable a dropdown through Excel VBA in internet explorer, however I can't manage to click the second child `DIV`. Although I can `debug.print` the contents of the dropdown, i can't manage to `fireevent` on  the `DIV` inside. This is the source code i am dealing with and what i did so far.

```
<div style="border-width: 1px; z-index: 1018; visibility: visible; height: 238px; width: 304px; left: 1566px; top: 144px;" role="presentation" id="x-auto-1048" class="x-combo-list x-ignore x-component x-border "><div tabindex="0" hidefocus="true" id="x-auto-318" class=" x-view x-combo-list-inner x-component  x-unselectable" style="overflow-x: hidden; padding: 0px; border-width: 0px; height: 238px; width: 304px;" unselectable="on">   <div class="x-combo-list-item x-panel-header ">&nbsp;Actions</div><div class="x-combo-list-item ">Add Lead Disposition</div><div class="x-combo-list-item  x-view-highlightrow x-combo-selected">Add Lead Assignment Priority</div><div class="x-combo-list-item x-panel-header ">Audits</div><div class="x-combo-list-item ">Account Settings</div><div class="x-combo-list-item x-panel-header ">Actions</div><div class="x-combo-list-item ">Add Lead Disposition</div><div class="x-combo-list-item ">Add Lead Assignment Priority</div><div class="x-combo-list-item x-panel-header ">Audits</div><div class="x-combo-list-item ">Account Settings</div></div></div>
```

And this what I did until now

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim ie As Object
Dim button As Variant
Dim var As String: var = ActiveCell.Value


Dim disp As Object
Dim dis As Object
Dim innnerr As Variant
Dim i               As Long: i = 0
ReDim innnerr(1000)
Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
ie.Visible = True
 With ie
    .Visible = True
    .navigate "http://controlpanel.sukutrade.verio/index.html#account-overview?sukuAccountUsername=" & var
    While .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Wend
End With
 'Wait some to time for loading the page
While ie.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

ie.document.getElementById("x-auto-317-input").Click



Set disp = ie.document.getElementById("x-auto-1048").getElementsByTagName("div")


For Each dis In disp
    innnerr(i) = dis.innerText
    If dis.innerText = "Add Lead Disposition" Then dis.fireevent "onclick"
    i = i + 1: Exit For
Next dis


Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))


ie.Quit
End Sub
```

What I need is to click on the second child which has the innertext "Add Lead Disposition".

EDIT: With the answer I got below, the iteration is working fine however the `Click` event is not firing. I tried `.Focus` and `Onclick` with `FireEvent` without a solution. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried like this? It should work.

```
Dim post As Object

For Each post In IE.document.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item")
    If InStr(post.innerText, "Add Lead Disposition") > 0 Then post.Click: Exit For
Next post
```

Comment: If it fails, try to do the same with a `space` at the end of the class name like `.getElementsByClassName("x-combo-list-item ")`.

Comment: it is iterating successfully but after the 2nd iteration the click event isn’t firing. Should we use something like fireevent?